# I am getting the below error in IBM cloud while trying to configure a service in free tier (lite)

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud

Your account has not been authorized to select the Lite plan. Upgrade your account to a paid IBM Cloud account to create an instance of a paid plan of the service.

Service is analytics engine and I have lite account

I am trying to create a spark-hadoop service. What should i do to get around this.

Comment: What service are you trying to create? Do you mean "Analytics Engine"? And what type of account do you have?

Comment: Yes analytics engine, I have lite account the free one

Comment: And your account was created in which region and in which region did you try to create the service? Both need to match